# How can I format a series of dates from long string of numbers?

Tags: php, date, format, word-wrap

I have a string of numbers that represent multiple dates. Let's say it's: 112620141129201412252014. That number represents November 26th, 2014 - November 29th, 2014 - December 25th, 2014.

I'd like to format it so that it looks something like [11, 26, 2014], [11, 29, 2014], [12, 25, 2014].

I can get it almost the way I want it with wordwrap:

```
$date = wordwrap( $date , 8, '], [' , true );
$date = "[" . $date . "]";

echo $date;
```

Which returns: [11262014], [11292014], [12252014]

What else can I use to get it in the format I want?

Comment: easy with substr() [alternative preg_splat or plain regular expressions] ( i hope days and months less than 10 have a leading 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, considering your days and months are always represented in two digits. For example, 3rd November 2014 should be `11032014` and not `1132014`.

```
<?php

$list = "112620141129201412252014";
$newlist = "";

while (!empty($list))
{
  $newlist = $newlist . "[" . substr($list, 0, 2) . "," . substr($list, 2, 2) . "," . substr($list, 4, 4) . "]";
  $list = substr($list, 8);  // remove from $list the date we just added to $newlist
  if (!empty($list))
    {
      $newlist = $newlist . ",";
    }
}

echo $newlist;

?>
```

Hope that helped `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) functions:

```php
echo implode(', ', array_map(function($val) {
        $val = substr_replace($val, ',', 4, 0);
        $val = substr_replace($val, ',', 2, 0);
        return '[' . $val . ']';
    }, str_split($input_string, 8))
);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/225657)</kbd>